# How can I send an XML string to an ASCX Repeater Control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ascx

I'm writing a Repeater Control in an ascx file which renders some info as a row that comes from a complex search. In an aspx file I have the query to retrieve a DataView that gives me the XML string with the info needed to feed the Repeater. The problem is that I don't know how can I pass the XML string (or the DataView or DataSet) from the aspx to the ascx file so as I can render the info.

Thank you.

Comment: Parse your XML into an IEnumerable and supply it as `Repeater.DataSource = <some data source>`

Comment: Where exactly do I have to put that sentence? In the html call for the ascx? like `<data:data ID="data" runat="server" />` Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expose a property or a method on the User Control so that the page referencing the `ASCX` control can receive the XML and do something with it (bind it to your repeater).

You can perfectly create a method inside your ASCX control like this:

```
public void BindXml(string xml)
{

    //bind the xml to the repeater
}
```

As a property...

```
public string XMLData { set 
                        { 
                          //use a DataSet to load the xml passed and bind it to 
                          //the repeater
                          DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                          dataset.ReadXml(value);
                          repeater.DataSource=dataset; repeater.DataBind(); 
                          }
                        }
```

The aspx page can call the method like so:

```
yourusercontrol.BindXML(xml);
```

Or the property:

```
yourusercontrol.XMLData=xml;
```

Comment: I think that I can pass directly the DataSet object instead of writing it to an XML and then creating another DataSet on the ascx control. Thanks!